# Displaying divs in a line within the header

Tags: html, css

Yo! So i've been been curious about the whole WordPress thing lately and i was going to use a site i made for another company by just changing colors and such. In the header where the menu and logo is, i want social icons they can click on but when i tried adding one of the icons the menu hopped under the header for some odd reason.

```css
.Header {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
.menubutton {
  font-family: 'source_sans_prolight';
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
  color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
.menu {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
  width: 100px;
}
.dropdown a {
  font-family: 'source_sans_prolight';
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #CBCBCB;
  color: white;
}
.menu:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}
.menu:hover .menubutton {
  background-color: #303030;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
}
.Logo {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 4px;
}
.socialbutton1 {}
```

```html
<div class="Header">

  <div class="Logo">

    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="css/images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
    </a>

  </div>

  <div class="social">

    <div class="socialbutton1">
      <img src="css/images/facebook1.svg" alt="Facebook">
    </div>


  </div>

  <div class="menu">

    <button class="menubutton">
      MENU
    </button>

    <div class="dropdown">

      <a href="#social" class="smoothScroll">
    Our Products
    </a>

      <a href="#kontakt" class="smoothScroll">
    Contact Us
    </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add float to socialbutton.

```
.socialbutton1 {
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: I tried float:right and float:left but the menu still remains under the header :(

Comment: Oh nvm, the float:left removes the whole header.. Lol

Comment: and also add to header class float:left;

Comment: Oh awesome, thanks.. Do you happen to know if i can place it left to the menu by using float:right? Currently the menu sits left to the social button if i attempt to do that..